# Changing the vertical height from ellipsoid to a local vertical CRS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, gdalwarp

i have a set of bathymetric data measured in UTM Zone 35 with the ETRS Datum and having the heights from the ellipsoid due to using an RTK base station. Can i transform these raster data sets from the ellipsoid height to Constanta Height (Epsg:5781 http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/5781/ ) by using either ArcGis or maybe in gdal? I have tried with ArcGis 10.5 using the project raster tool and choosing the vertical datum there but nothing seems to happen with the heights.

Comment: You probably have a local ellipsoid which serves as the reference for your heights. Thus, you need to switch from the global ellipsoid (probably wgs84) to global Cartesian coordinates and then to your local ellipsoid (and probably to your geoid model after in order to have the orthometric height as measured on the field).

Answer (score 1):

As I can't add an image within the comments I precise my thoughts here:

Here is the idea to switch between global (mainly based on the WGS84 or GRS80 ellipsoid) heights as measured by RTK receivers and local orthometric heights:
[image: from ellipsoidal height to orthometric heights]

Be careful, the global WGS84 ellipsoid may not be the same as the ellipsoid used in your country, in this case you will have to switch first to global Cartesian coordinates and then to your local ellipsoid. And only after, to the to orthometric heights (or other kind of heights) based on the geoid as defined in your country (may be interpolated from lots geophysical measurements).

You may be interested to have a glance at theses links:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Heights
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/wkflw-converting-from-orthometric-to-ellipsoidal-heights.htm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_ellipsoid
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: Esri product engineer

We're just now adding support for vertical transformations for rasters this year, so it's not available to you yet.

I don't know if GDAL has added vertical transformation support yet.

[EPSG Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org) lists transformations between Constanta and EVRF2000 or EVRF2007. The transformations use a vertical offset and slope method. ArcGIS does have these transformations but only for vector data starting with 10.4.1. They do not list any transformations between EVRF2000 or EVRF2007 and ETRF/ETRS2000 (GRS80) or WGS84. For this conversion, you would probably use EGG97 or a latter geoid model.

Comment: > I don't know if GDAL has added vertical transformation support yet.

It has in the recent GDAL 2.2 release, although the available set of transformations is quite limited.

Answer (score 0):

GDAL can now do vertical CRS transforms using compond CRS. For example, WGS84 ellipsoid with EGM96 elevation can be specified like EPSG:4326+5773. Once you know the compond CRS definitions, `gdalwarp` can do the transform.

```
gdalwarp  -s_srs <source compond srs> -t_srs <target compond srs> input.tif output.tif
```

See more details https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/10/26/convert-between-orthometric-and-ellipsoidal-elevations-using-gdal/